# Angular Ag Grid Clear Text Input Issue

Tags: angular, ag-grid

[image]

Hi, I am using Ag Grid enterprise version 17.0 with Angular 5. The text fields seem to have an issue. I am unable to clear the values in text fields. The cross symbol associated with the text field as per the attachment is not clearing the text on click of it. Can you please let me know how to make this clear text field work using the cross symbol ? Please find the attachment for your reference.

Column Definition

```
{
        headerName: 'Contact Name',
        formEditable: true,
        isRequired: true,
        width: 150,
        minWidth: 150,
        suppressPaste: false,
        field: 'contactName',
        suppressFilter: true,

}
```

Comment: Can you include your code as well, for the table's column definitions

Comment: Can I check your code for your custom cell editor? Are you using a custom component for it? https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editor/#example-cell-editing-using-angular-components

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question with table column definition. The contact name appears with a cross symbol but when I click on it, nothing happens.

Comment: Hi, A wrapper has been created on top of current ag grid but for the text fields the usual ag grid text field has been used.

Comment: it works. check this plunk https://plnkr.co/edit/S6PcE5nLoWtBKgNls2jy?p=preview for reference. OR, provide us a plunk reproducing the issue

Comment: Thanks for the update. I will check if i can provide you with plunk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to create a demo thanks to the plunkr provided by @Paritosh. By Ag-grid's convention, you should create a custom component using the `frameworkComponents` and `ICellEditorAngularComp`.

You may check it out over here for the full demo, and refer to the column named 'Numeric': https://plnkr.co/edit/QWPNv9IBvaBuv8yAdWYg?p=preview

Once you are on the demo, refer to `app/numeric-editor.component.ts`.

Basically, I have added a 'cross' button on the input, and attached a `click` event binding to that button:

```
<div class="search_field">
    <input #input (keydown)="onKeyDown($event)" [(ngModel)]="value">
    <button type="button" (click)="clear()"style="position: absolute;top: 3px;right: 10px;">
      <span>&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

And this is how I defined my `clear()` method. The idea is to set it as undefined (or empty string), and return that value respectively.

```
clear() {
  this.value = null;
  console.log(this.value);
  return this.value;
}
```

The styling may not be perfect, but I hope you get my idea

Comment: Thanks for the update. I got the idea. I will try to implement the functionality which you have mentioned

Comment: @Nithin yup, do let me know if it works on your end too.

Comment: You should not need to do this. Don't go into x-y problem. Here the issue is, the x icon is provided by IE, which is not working in OP's post. Creating custom editor component is overhead here

Comment: @wentjun   Hi, Thanks for your kind support. I have implemented your solution and it works fine. But there is one question. May i know why you are setting this.value = undefined instead of null ?

Comment: @Nithin oh, my bad! I should set it to null instead, since I am actually assigning a value to it.

Comment: Would you mind to have a look at this issue and address it ?[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56022346/angular-ag-grid-single-click-issue-with-ie-11?noredirect=1#comment98688411_56022346]

Comment: @wentjun- can you tell me sir..how to reset input value in different component?